# ArgumentException throws when sort a column with null value in the dynamic collection

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to sort the dynamic collection and it is working fine when the column doesn't have null value. If the column having null value, then sorting the dynamic collection throws ArgumentException.Here is the sample [dynamiccollectionsimplesample.zip](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/storage/attachments/47502-dynamiccollectionsimplesample.zip) .

```
`var dt = GetDataTable();
var dynamicCollection = new ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject>();
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    ExpandoObject dyn = new ExpandoObject();
    dynamicCollection.Add(dyn);
    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        var dic = (IDictionary<string, object>)dyn;
        dic[column.ColumnName] = row[column];
    }
}
var expressionFunc = GetExpressionFunc("OrderID");
var source = dynamicCollection.AsQueryable();
var sourceType = source.ElementType;
var paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, sourceType.Name);
var cExp = Expression.Constant("OrderID");
var iExp = Expression.Invoke(expressionFunc, new Expression[] { cExp, paramExpression });
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(iExp, paramExpression);
var orderedSource = source.Provider.CreateQuery(
Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),"OrderBy",new Type[] { source.ElementType,lambda.Body.Type },source.Expression,
lambda));
var enumerable = orderedSource as IEnumerable;
if (enumerable.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
{
}`
```

Could anyone please update me, why sorting with null value in dynamic collection throws exception?
For null values in the dynamic collection, null values are shown as Curly phrase{} like this shown in below image,
[Value of the null value column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v8Xx.png)

Comment: The default sorter, is usually a Instance Function. And instance functions can not be called on null references. And rather then running into a "Object reference not set to a instance of object" exception, it throws a Argument one. You should try to provide a custom sorter, where you can filter out the null case.

Comment: A Date cannot be null in c#.  I will see if a can fix the posted code in teh zip file.

Comment: the issue is with this line :  collection.Rows.Add(null, "h", 978.76, 458.21, 675.99, null);  The DateTime is null.  Instead of null use : new DateTime().  This will set the date to 1/1/01.  Then later you can ignore by adding a Where and filter for dates > 1/1/2000.

Comment: It's our customer requirement . I set the numeric column and  DateTime column as null value.Then, the ArgumentException is occurred.